# Is there a way to view Dart pub serve output in WebStorm in a more 'build-error-list' way?

Tags: ide, dart, webstorm

I'm experimenting with Dart/Angular/WebStorm for the first time. One thing which I've found a little jarring has been the build->error cycle. In Visual Studio, I am used to this work flow:

1. Write some code
2. Running a build
3. Having a fresh list of errors being created
4. Fixing a subset of them (some or all)
5. Go to 1.

I'm wondering what is the workflow with Dart?

I have the following issues:

1. I can't figure out a way to just run pub/transformer/whatever-it-is-that-roughly-equates-to-a-build. The only way I can do this is by attempting to run a configuration
2. When the transformer is run, it just dumps a gigantic error output to the Pub Serve window. It does not clear the existing output, so I end up with duplicate error or errors I've already fixed. So I'm left manually scrolling through the list but taking care not to  So I must manually right-click and clear the output window and rerun it.
3. The transformer only runs when it detects a file change. This makes sense, but when coupled with 1 and 2, I've often cleared the output and I am running the transformer just to see a fresh list of errors. Which I don't get.

So my workflow becomes:

1. Write some code.
2. Run
3. Close dartium browser window (I'm not actually interested in running it, just seeing my errors)
4. See a bunch of errors. Realise that I didn't clear the errors from the previous run.
5. Right click and clear the pub serve output window.
6. Run again
7. Close dartium browser window again
8. Realise that the transformer has not run because it already ran in steps 1-3 and I haven't changed a file.
9. Change a file
10. Run again
11. Close dartium browser window again
12. Scroll through error list to find errors to fix

I find this a little cumbersome. Perhaps there is a philosophical point here on relying too much on my tooling to identify and fix errors (although I thought that was the entire point) but I'm just wondering what other people do to simplify this - I'm faintly surprised I appear to be alone in this.

Answer (score 3):

You may run 'Pub Build' (available in the right-click menu of `pubspec.yaml` file and also right in the editor when pubspec is open). It is not incremental, so it runs longer (i.e. runs from scratch each time) but it gives you the list of errors just as if you've cleared Pub Serve output, edited each file in the project, started run configuration and closed a browser.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes errors are only shown when `pub serve` generates output the first time. For reloads some errors aren't shown anymore.
I'm not sure if this is a limitation of `pub serve` or a bug in the transformers.

`pub serve` is going to be replaced a new build system that builds to disk instead of in-memory only.
DDC isn't perfect yet either, but it's the future and I'd suggest to try this instead. There are known performance problems with Angular, but they are working on it.

See also 
- https://webdev.dartlang.org/tools/dartdevc
- https://github.com/dart-lang/build

Comment: > `pub serve is going to be replaced by DDC`

I thought pub serve simply works in DDC mode when configured so, so 'replace' isn't a correct word here. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Right, I mixed up DDC with the build stuff they are working on.